# substring using \(backslash) in java

Tags: java, string, exception

I want to get file name from complete path of file.
Input : "D://amol//1/\15_amol.jpeg"
Expected Output : 15_amol.jpeg

I have written below code for this

```
public class JavaApplication9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fname="D://amol//1/\15_amol.jpeg";
        System.out.println(fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf("/")));
        System.out.println(fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf("\\")));
    }
}
```

but getting below output :

```
_amol.jpeg

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
String index out of range: -1   
  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1927)   
  at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:6)

C:\Users\lakhan.kamble\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
 Java returned: 1
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash in the original String literal.  So `String fname="D://amol//1/\\15_amol.jpeg";`.  Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: `File.getName()` will do this for you (once you fix the typo); don't reinvent the wheel. `System.out.println(new File("D://amol//1/\\15_amol.jpeg").getName());`

Answer (score 1):

The string `\15` is an "octal escape" for the carriage return character (0x0d, 13 decimal).  There are two possibilities here.

1. You really meant `\15` to be the octal escape, in which case you are trying to create a filename with an embedded newline.  The actual contents of `fname` in this case could be expressed as

   ```
   "D://amol//1/" + "\n" + "_amol.jpeg";
   ```

   Windows will prevent that from happening and your program will throw an `IOException`.
2. You really meant

   ```
   String fname="D://amol//1/\\15_amol.jpeg";
   ```

   In this case the extra backslash is redundant and will be ignored by Windows because the filename will resolve (in Windows path terms) to `D:\amol\1\\15_amol.jpeg` and adjacent directory separators collapse to a single separator. So you could just omit the extra backslash altogether without changing the effective path.

As to your exception, the string as shown DOES NOT contain a backslash character (case 1 above), so

```
fname.lastIndexOf("\\")
```

returned -1, causing the exception

Comment: Your answer was sufficiently insightful that it inspired me to retract my close vote on the question.  Definitely worth having an answer like this.  Although if I were going to be ultra-picky, I'd point out that an embedded newline isn't _quite_ the same thing as an embedded carriage return.

Comment: Thanks, I also updated the answer to address the _actual_ immediate question :-)